# Python selenium msedge does not work with headless mode disabled. Message: unknown error: msedge failed to start: crashed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with a python selenium web scraper that uses microsoft edge as a webdriver. The msedgedriver works fine only when one of these is present:

```py
edge_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Edge_user_data")
edge_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

When i try to use them both, the error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test17.py", line 3414, in <module>
    slower_process(urls, result_file_path)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test17.py", line 3338, in slower_process
    result = check_url(url)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test17.py", line 42, in check_url
    result = 123_check(url, username)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test17.py", line 534, in 123_check
    driver = initialize_driver5()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test17.py", line 321, in initialize_driver5
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options, service=service)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 290, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: msedge failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF74D583DB2+61490]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF74D516002+740642]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D2EB8AE]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D31CBFE]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D317F13]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D35B7F8]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D3536E3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D325EAA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D32518B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D326634]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF74D748D69+1207369]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74D3A5304]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF74D4690F1+32273]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF74D4619E9+1801]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF74D747944+1202212]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF74D51E998+19784]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF74D51AE54+4612]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF74D51AF86+4918]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF74D50F451+713073]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF87E917614+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF87FD226B1+33]
```

I read a lot on StackOverflow and Git, but no solution has worked for me. Here's my code:

```py
def initialize_driver5(): # Microsoft Edge    
    # Define Edge options
    edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

    edgepath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
    edge_options.setBinary = edgepath
    service = webdriver.EdgeService(service_args=['--log-level=SEVERE', '--disable-build-check'])

    # Using the user profile
    edge_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Edge_user_data")

    # Options
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL) 
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
    edge_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=0')
    edge_options.add_argument('--no-first-run')
    edge_options.add_argument('--no-default-browser-check')

    edge_options.add_argument('--headless')
    edge_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
    edge_options.add_argument('--start-maximized') 
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars') 
    edge_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['disable-popup-blocking'])

    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options, service=service)
    
    return driver
```

**What I have tried:**

- Giving msedge permissions
- Reseting msedge browser
- Duplicating the profile folder
- Deleting and recreating the user profile folder
- Deleting and downloading a new msedgedriver
- Indicating the executable path
- Setting add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=0') and other suggested arguments
- Closing all the edge instances running in the background
- Reseting my PC

Comment: The problem was solved by changing --headless=new. I hope it will help someone if the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already solved the problem, but I wanted to point out another solution, that does not require a webdriver. You can use `playwright`, which is a pretty new python library, and works with many browsers, to install `playwright`, run these commands:

`pip install playwright`

`playwright install`

Then, you can use this code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="msedge")
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com')
    browser.close()
```

This should give the desired output. To learn more about `playwright`, check out the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro).